# AnyLogic - pickup (container size)

Tags: anylogic

[Screenshot]
I'm sorry it's in german..

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCc12.png)I have a problem with a pickup element in AnyLogic. I have two agents: pallets and pieces.

If an order arrives I combine the two with a pickup element (pallet in inPort) with "at least 4 pieces" and I also set up a parameter on the Agent `pallet` with the name `amountofpieces`.

I now want to know exactly how many pieces there are in the container `pallet`, so that I can add the amount of pieces to my stock variable.

With: `Agent.amountofpieces = container.contents().size()` I get a error note.

Also `Agent.amountofpieces = pallet.contents().size()` is not working.

I later want to add it to a variable (name: `stock`). My code now is: `stock += + Agent.amountofpieces`.

Do you maybe have an idea how to solve it?

Or is there another posibility to get the amount of agents that went out as "one" new agent?

Comment: did you try "agent" instead of "Agent"? Java is case-sensitive and these two have massively different meanings. Also, what is the error? Do share some screenshots :)

Comment: I added a screenshot, the error message states: agent cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :)

agent.contents().size() works without any parameters or anything else.